If a series diverges, there exists a sequence convergent to zero such that the series of their termwise product is divergent.
Let $\sum y_n$ diverge. Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0$ and $\sum x_ny_n$ diverges.
Is this true? How should I prove this?

Choose the $x_i$ in batches. Make the product series reach 1, then make it reach 2, then make it reach 3, etc.

@Karl sorry I don't understand what you wrote.

While you've posed a problem that can be resolved by reasoned mathematical argument, you have left the problem statement "bare", i.e. without essential context.  Please edit the Question's body to explain where you encountered the problem, what prior results it might have been intended to illustrate, or why it is important to you.  In its present form it is drawing a significant number of Close Votes for lack of context.

I think what @Karl suggests is something like:
Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_{n}$ diverges to $\infty.$ Let $1 < n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \cdots$ be such that $\sum_{n=1}^{n_1-1}y_n\geq 1$,  $\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2-1}y_n\geq 2$,  $\sum_{n=n_2}^{n_3-1}y_n\geq 3$, etc. Let $x_n=1$ for $1\leq n < n_1$, $x_n=\tfrac{1}{2}$ for $n_1\leq n < n_2$, $x_n=\tfrac{1}{3}$ for $n_2\leq n < n_3$, etc. Then $x_n\to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n y_{n}$ diverges to $\infty.$
You can be slightly fancier and modify the sequence $x_n$ by changing the $x_n$ above to $0$ for all the $n$ where $y_n<0$. Thereby making $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n y_{n}$ a series whose terms all are $\geq0.$
Edit:
As pointed out by @geetha290krm one should address the case where the sum does not diverge to infinity.
If the sum of $y_n<0$ and the sum of $y_n>0$ both are convergent, then so is the sum of all the $y_n.$ If the sum of $y_n>0$ is divergent, set $x_n=0$ for all $n$ with $y_n<0$ and use @Karl's  argument detailed above on the remaining subscripts.

For many, a series diverges if it does not converge. In that case this answer is wrong.

Another argument would be to reduce the case of $\sum y_n$ to $\sum |y_n|$ by including the sign of $y_n$ in the multipliers $x_n$.
